# Is it possible to detect a terminal needing a `reset`?

Tags: console, console-application, reset, xterm, pty

Program that I write often crashes leaving terminal in a S-Lang library state (similar to ncurses). I would want to add a check into development's branch Makefile main `all` target for such an improper state and and an automatic invocation of `reset` command. How to approach this task?

Answer (score 0):

[`reset`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization) does two things; you can write a shell script which detects one of them:

- it resets the terminal I/O *modes* (which a shell script can inspect using `stty`)
- it sends escape sequences to the terminal (which more often than not will alter things in the terminal for which there is no suitable query/report escape sequence).

For the latter, you would find it challenging to determine the currently selected character set, e.g., line-drawing.  If the terminal's set to show line-drawing characters, that's the usual reason for someone wanting to run **`reset`** (e.g., cat'ing a binary file to the screen).

There happens to be a VT320 feature ([**`DECCIR`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps-$-w:Ps-=-1.1E5B)) which can provide this information (which xterm implements):

[image: xterm, with DECCCIR]

but with regard to other terminals, you're unlikely to find it implemented:

[image: iTerm2, with DECCIR]

(iTerm2 doesn't do it)

[image: VTE with DECCIR]

(nor does VTE).  You can read an extract from the VT510 manual describing the feature on [*`vt100.net`*](https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECCIR.html)